# how to change URL in multi language web site- Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, multilingual

I am working on multi language web site. it works fine with each IP_Address, the problem is that I want to make  the URL changed after it renders, in the way it shows whats the language code in the URL.
here is my route config

```
namespace global_vrf
{
  public class RouteConfig
   {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, language="" }
        );
    }
 }
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Globalization;
using global_vrf.GeoIpService;

namespace global_vrf.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index(string language)
    {
      if (language!="") 
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        }
        else if(language=="") 
        {
            try
            {
                string userIpAddress = this.Request.UserHostAddress;
                ViewBag.userIpAddress = userIpAddress;

                GeoIPService service = new GeoIPService();
                GeoIP output = service.GetGeoIP(userIpAddress);
                ViewBag.userIpAddress = userIpAddress;
                var country_name = output.CountryName;
                ViewBag.cnam = country_name;
                var country_code = output.CountryCode;
                ViewBag.ccode = country_code;

                 if (country_code == "FRA")
                {
                    language = "fr-FR";
                }
                    //and I will check the other languages here


            }
            catch
            {
                string userIpAddress = "209.95.51.176";
                ViewBag.userIpAddress = userIpAddress;

                GeoIPService service = new GeoIPService();
                GeoIP output = service.GetGeoIP(userIpAddress);
                ViewBag.userIpAddress = userIpAddress;
                var country_name = output.CountryName;
                ViewBag.cnam = country_name;
                var country_code = output.CountryCode;
                ViewBag.ccode = country_code;
                language = "en-us";

            }

        }
```

Appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute routing in mvc

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Globalization;
using global_vrf.GeoIpService;

namespace global_vrf.Controllers
{
RoutePrefix("Example Name")]
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index(string language)
    {
      if (language!="") 
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        }
        else if(language=="") 
        {
            try
            {
                string userIpAddress = this.Request.UserHostAddress;
                ViewBag.userIpAddress = userIpAddress;

                GeoIPService service = new GeoIPService();
                GeoIP output = service.GetGeoIP(userIpAddress);
                ViewBag.userIpAddress = userIpAddress;
                var country_name = output.CountryName;
                ViewBag.cnam = country_name;
                var country_code = output.CountryCode;
                ViewBag.ccode = country_code;

                 if (country_code == "FRA")
                {
                    language = "fr-FR";
                }
                    //and I will check the other languages here


            }
            catch
            {
                string userIpAddress = "209.95.51.176";
                ViewBag.userIpAddress = userIpAddress;

                GeoIPService service = new GeoIPService();
                GeoIP output = service.GetGeoIP(userIpAddress);
                ViewBag.userIpAddress = userIpAddress;
                var country_name = output.CountryName;
                ViewBag.cnam = country_name;
                var country_code = output.CountryCode;
                ViewBag.ccode = country_code;
                language = "en-us";

            }

        }
```

Comment: thanks for your care. it has an error `Error 1 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods` .how does it work then?need some explain if possible

Comment: RoutePrefix[("admin/index")].  And above action route[("index")] and it's works only in MVC 5

Comment: I think that's not useful for me that much because my language is going to be set on my index action not before

Comment: i think my codes are complicated. I will work more on it. any way thanks